# Unable to write data into Excel file cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to write a String into an existing Excel file cell using Java and apache library poi. Here is my method:

```
public void setSuccessMessageInExcellFile(File uploadFile, HttpServletResponse response) {          

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        HSSFCell cell = excelSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Imported");

        fileInputStream.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(uploadFile);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

there is no error but **"Imported"** text is **not available** in my **Excel** file.

Comment: Where is your "uploadFile" located? Is it managed by the server? Can you explain your use case a little bit? The presence of `HttpServletResponse` makes me wonder if you are actually uploading a file and trying to change it....

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your file exists, writable and has the right Excel version. After that you should change your code like that, because you are getting a `NullPointerException` otherwise:

```
public void setSuccessMessageInExcellFile(File uploadFile, HttpServletResponse response) {


    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        HSSFCell cell = excelSheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Imported");

        fileInputStream.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(uploadFile);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

And better would be putting the closables in the try as argument like that:

```
try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream); 
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(uploadFile)) {            
        HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        HSSFCell cell = excelSheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Imported"); 
        workbook.write(out);         
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am sure my file Exist But how can i give Permission for writable

Comment: Be sure the file is not open in Excel as you try to write on it.